# Force between two current carrying parallel wires, multiple proof?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

Having two current carrying (currents $I'$ and $I$) wires of length $a$ parallel to the $z$-axis, one with end points $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,a)$ and one from $(a,0,0)$ to $(a,0,a)$, I'm looking for the force on the second one due to the first one. Here is my problem:

I know I'm suppose to get (which I get by finding the magnetic field,...) $$F=\frac{\mu_0II'}{2\pi a}a$$ but I also know that I can compute this with the formula
$$F=\frac{-\mu_0II'}{4\pi a}\int_0^a\int_0^a (dr'.dr) \frac{(r'-r)}{|r'-r|^3}$$ where $r$ and $r'$ are along the wires. When I tried, I got rid of the absolute value by separating the second integral in two parts : $\int_0^r$ and $\int_r^a$. But I don't get anywhere near the solution! Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bad-diagram.

[image]

This is how I proceed.

Between two parallel current-carrying wires, the magnetic-force is given by 
(mu*i1*i2*l)/(2*pi*r), where, mu=magnetic-permeability of medium, i1,i2: currents, l=length of wire on which force is to be found, r=perpendicular separation between the wires.

so, considering diagram, and given data, magnetic force on second wire, due to firstwire is:

(mu *  I'  *  I   *  a)/(2*pi*a)

= (mu *  I'  *  I )/(2*pi)